# Proving $\tan(z)$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How can I prove that $\tan(z)$ is an analytic function?

I tried with the expansion for $\tan(A+B)$. Couldn't complete. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the Cauchy-Riemann equation for proving it is analytic? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i'm not able to reduce the formula tanA+tanB/1-tanAtanB to u+iv form.Only when that is possible would i be able to get the CR equations. I need help reducing the above expansion of tan(A+B).

Comment: If you can prove that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are each analytic, then you are done. The quotient of two analytic functions is again an analytic function. (Edit: Whenever the denominator is nonzero, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(iy) = \frac{\sin(iy)}{\cos(iy)}$

Also,

$$\sin(iy) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{-y}-e^y) = i\sinh(y).$$

$$\cos(iy) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-y}+e^y) = \cosh(y).$$

So we have:

$$\tan(z) = \frac{\tan(x)+i\tanh(y)}{1-i\tan(x)\tanh(y)}.$$

From here, try rationalising the denominator and move forward.

Comment: i saw that in quora already...how do u suppose to rationalise the denominator??other than using a conjugate?m

Comment: Yes, you should multiply through the conjugate. Perhaps let $$\tan(x) = u$$ and $$\tanh(y) = v$$, that might make it a bit clearer.